# Oracle 12c Client Compatible with 9i Server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-9i

I'm developing on a new .NET application that needs to read/write data from an Oracle 9i database. I've got it working with ODAC 11.2.0.4 which comes with Instant Client 11.2. I had selected this version because I had read that Oracle 12c Client was only backwards Compatible to version 10g release 2 servers. Unfortunately I can't find that reference.

I would prefer to use latest version of ODAC 12.2, but I need to confirm that I'll still be able to connect to a 9i database.

**Note:** All the links I found to Oracle Compatibility charts are hidden behind an Oracle registration wall that isn't currently working for new signups. So I'm asking the question here.

Comment: Why would you prefer using ODAC 12.2 with the 9i database, given that ODAC 11.2 already works?

Comment: The app also connects to 12c databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from behind the Oracle registration wall:

[Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=207303.1)

```
Client Version: 12.2.0 or 12.1.0
Server Version: 9.2.0
Supported: No #3
```

Where:

```
#3: An ORA-3134 error is correctly reported when attempting to connect to this version.
```

So I would not expect it to work at all.

Comment: Thanks. Much better than the public page which says it is supported, which I assume wasn't updated when 12c was released: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/multipledbs-089665.html